# DbContext - how do I stop my database from creating new records when I'm updating them?

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, razor, dbcontext

My database keeps creating new records when it should be updating the current one. Razor-Pages project, asp.net 2.2.

What should be happening:

1. Retrieving email from asp.net Identity user class
2. Finding match in table Companies by comparing email == email
3. Updating records
4. Saving changes

And instead of updating, it creates new records.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    var email = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);

    var company = _context.Companies.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Email == email);
    Firma = user.Firma;

    return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    var email = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);

    var company = _context.Companies.First(a => a.Email == email);

    company.Navn = Input.Firma;
    company.Postnr = Input.Postnr;
    company.Sted = Input.Sted;
    company.Beskrivelse = Input.Beskrivelse;

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into using locking?

Comment: @J.Murray in that scenario will throw an exception, but the problem he has will still here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_context.Companies.Update(company);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is there are record in Companies that matches the email that you are passing in. Try FirstOrDefault instead and check for null.

Comment: Just removed all of the code in OnPostAsync, and it's still creating new records. So frustrating right now, can't figure out why it's happening..

Comment: Downgraded my project from 2.2 to 2.1, and now it works all good. Thanks for the reply though.